# Manual garbage collection in Python

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Is there any way to manually remove an object which the garbage collection refuses to get rid of even when I call `gc.collect()`? Working in Python 3.0

Comment: Don't know about Python but some garbage collectors will sometimes mistakenly think things are still in use because they find what *appear* to be references to these objects (but actually aren't). In such cases there's not much you can do.

Comment: Also, you should move to Python 3.1 ASAP.  3.0 has a number of known problems and is no longer supported.

Comment: As soon as I finish honors, I intend to.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html?highlight=gc#gc.get_referrers), `gc.get_referrers(thatobject)` will tell you *why* the object is still alive (do it right after a `gc.collect()` to make sure the undesired "liveness" is gonna be persistent).  After that, it's somehow of a black art;-).  You'll often find that some of the referrers are lists (so WHY is that list referring to `thatobject`? you can `.remove` it in an emergency mode, but making the normal code sound is better...), and, even more often, `dict`s (many of whose may be `__dict__`s of some class instance or other -- often not trivial to find out which one... again, brute-force removal is sometimes an expedient emergency solution, but never a sustainable long-range one!-).

Answer (score 4):

If the GC is refusing to destroy it, it's because you have a reference to it somewhere. Get rid of the reference and it will (eventually) go. For example:

```
myRef = None
```

Keep in mind that GC may not *necessarily* destroy your object unless it needs to.

If your object is holding resources not under the management of Python (e.g., some trickery with C code called from Python), the object should provide a resource release call so you can do it when you want rather than when Python decides.

Answer (score 4):

`del` Or `None` are your *only* friends

```
>>> a = "Hello"
>>> a = None
Or
>>> del a
```

Comment: Not necessarily true. The object just needs to be unreachable (or have an agreeably disposable ref-count, which very hopefully agrees with the former) to be eligible for reclamation.

Comment: `del a` doesn't delete the object (just a note; not implying that you imply that)

Comment: `a = None` and `del a` both decrement the reference counter of the object pointed to by `a`. So his answer is valid: if you do that everywhere the value is referred to, eventually its reference counter will reach zero and will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your Python is running on. [Here's good article](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-does-python-manage-memory.htm) that explains the details

Quoting:

In current releases of CPython, each new assignment to x inside the loop will release the previously allocated resource. Using GC, this is not guaranteed. If you want to write code that will work with any Python implementation, you should explicitly close the resource; this will work regardless of GC:

```
for name in big_list:
    x = Resource()
    do something with x
    x.close()
```