# dynamic memory allocation in python

Tags: python, memory, numpy, ram

I created a big multidimensional array `M` with `np.zeros((1000,1000))`. After certain number of operations, I don't need it anymore. How can I free a RAM dynamically during program's execution? Does `M=0` do it for me?

Comment: `M=0` will remove the reference, as will `del M`, and if that was the only reference, it should be freed immediately.

Comment: I trace the memory and I see that M=0 does not cause any effect on memory. That is why I am asking.

Comment: `del M` is also better IMHO, since `M` no longer pollutes the namespace your'e in.

Comment: @freude, are you sure it's the only reference to the object?

Comment: @freude Are you certain the `M` variable was the only reference to the array? Might help to include the relevant code snippet.

Comment: @freude you might get away with `M=0` on CPython but on Jython / IronPython which don't use reference counting, you'll have to wait for their garbage collector. Even with CPython you may still have references to `M` in other variables and they will mean `M` doesn't actually get deleted. Use `del M`

Comment: Also, bear in mind that to avoid fragmentation and performance costs, blocks of memory may be reserved even after being "freed".

Comment: Than you for the answer. It will be good to keep the variable M as a float number, since I am going to use it. I just want to reduce the matrix to a number saving some RAM.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1641762/171318

Comment: Even when the memory is reclaimed, Python isn't necessarily returning the memory to the OS, i.e., the process's memory allocation won't decrease. The memory may be reused later by the process, instead of it needing to request more from the OS.

Comment: @chepner Does it mean that if I load a huge matrix to ram once,there is no way free ram while my program is running? Can python use this memory freed by del  even if OS does not get it?

Comment: @freude: To the best of my knowledge, yes and yes.

Comment: @freude It's possible, but you should eliminate the other explanations as possibilities before you can draw that conclusion. I find it hard to believe that `numpy` would hold on to that much RAM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In *general* you can't. Even if you remove all the references to an object, it is left to the python implementation to re-use or free the memory. On CPython you could call [`gc.collect()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.collect) to force a garbage collection run. But while that may reclaim memory, it doesn't necessarily return it to the OS.

**But**: numpy is an extension module that does its own thing, and manages its own memory.

When I monitor the memory usage of a python process, I see the RAM usage (Resident Set Size) going down after `del(M)`

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: M = np.zeros((1000,1000))

In [3]: del(M)

In [4]:
```

Just after starting IPython:

```
slackbox:~> ps -u 77778
USER     PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TT  STAT STARTED    TIME COMMAND
rsmith 77778  0.0  0.5 119644 22692  0  S+    2:37PM 0:00.39 /usr/local/bin/py
```

After importing numpy (1):

```
slackbox:~> ps -u 77778
USER     PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TT  STAT STARTED    TIME COMMAND
rsmith 77778  1.0  0.8 168548 32420  0  S+    2:37PM 0:00.49 /usr/local/bin/py
```

After creating the array (2):

```
slackbox:~> ps -u 77778
USER     PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TT  STAT STARTED    TIME COMMAND
rsmith 77778  0.0  1.0 176740 40328  0  S+    2:37PM 0:00.50 /usr/local/bin/py
```

After the call to `del` (3):

```
slackbox:~> ps -u 77778
USER     PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TT  STAT STARTED    TIME COMMAND
rsmith 77778  0.0  0.8 168548 32496  0  S+    2:37PM 0:00.50 /usr/local/bin/py
slackbox:~>
```

So *in this case* using `del()` can reduce the amount of RAM used.

Note that there is an exception to this with numpy. Numpy can use memory allocated by another extension library. In that case the numpy object is marked that numpy doesn't own the memory, and freeing it is left to the other library.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [del](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) statement:

```
del M
```

And by the way, a `float64` array of shape `(1000, 1000)` takes only 7 Mb. If you're having memory problems, it's likely that the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways are there.......

1). del M

```
     But it will delete the array object it self.
```

2). M.clear()

```
     you can clear the array without deleting M object
```

Comment: The second way is just exactly what I am seeking. Thank you