# Python Memory Management Issue

Tags: python, memory-management

I have a question about memory management for a specific piece of python code that I have.  Here is the code

```
def combo_counter(file_path,title_body,validation=None,val_set=None,val_number=None):
    combo_count={}

    counter=0

    with open(file_path+"/Train.csv") as r:
        reader=csv.reader(r)
        next(r)
        if title_body=='body':
            for row in reader:
                if (validation is not None) and ((int(row[0])>val_set[0]) and (int(row[0])<val_set[-1])):
                    continue


                counter+=1
                if counter%10000==0:
                    print counter

                no_stops=body_parser(row)

                a=' '.join(no_stops)
                b=row[3]
                for x, y in product(a.split(), b.split()):
                    if x+" "+y in combo_count:
                        combo_count[x+" "+y]+=1
                    else:
                        combo_count[x+" "+y]=1
    return combo_count

def body_parser(row):
    soup=BS(row[2],'html')
    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name in bad_tags:
            tag.extract()
    code_removed=soup.renderContents()
    tags_removed=re.sub(r'<[^>]+>', '', code_removed)
    parse_punct=re.findall(r"[\w+#]+(?:[-'][\w+#]+)*|'|[-.(]+|\S[\w+#]*",tags_removed)
    no_punct=' '.join(w.lower() for w in parse_punct if w not in string.punctuation)
    no_stops=[b for b in no_punct.split(' ') if not b in stops]

    return no_stops
```

So basically I am reading a csv file line-by-line and parsing each line and then counting co-occurrances using a dictionary called combo_count.  The problem is that the dictionary, once exported, is only about 1.2GB however when I run this code, it uses much more memory than this.  But the only thing that I can see that would use up a substantial amount of memory is the dictionary. I suspect that something is using up memory that it shouldn't be.  After each row is processed, everything should be erased from memory except the counting dictionary.  Can anyone see anything in the code that would be using up memory aside from the dictionary? I suspect that it is somewhere in the body_parser function.

Comment: How large is your csv file?

Comment: It may just be that the gc isn't releasing memory because it isn't invoked. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641717/manual-garbage-collection-in-python and see if the memory consumption is still as high.

Comment: The original csv file is about 6GB. But I am not saving it in memory in any way.  I'm just reading each line, counting, then throwing that line away

Comment: I don't know what "exporting" a dictionary means, but strongly doubt that - whatever it means - the size of an "exported dictionary" bears any particularly useful relation to the memory size of a Python dictionary. How many keys are in the dictionary?  Exactly how much is "much more memory than this"? ...

Comment: I meant that the dictionary was later exported to a csv file where the keys were in one column and the values were in another column.  I was working under the assumption that the size of this csv file would be roughly the how much memory the dictionary took up.  If I'm wrong about that then maybe that is the reason for my confusion.  Anyhow, to answer your question, the number of keys in the dictionary is in the millions and the resulting csv file is 1.2GB and almost all of my RAM is used when this is run 7.7GB

Comment: Something to try:  simply replace the lines that add to `combo_count` with `pass` statements.  IOW, leave the dictionary empty.  If memory use is still outrageous, then you *know* the dict is not the problem.  Or if memory use is tiny, then you know the dict *is* the problem.  We have no idea how big your key strings are, so impossible to guess whether millions of keys "should" account for such high memory use.  Offhand, it does sound unlikely to me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[@user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1893354/user1893354)

You can use python's [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to check which variable is using more memory and never releasing it.

This add-on provides the decorator @profile that allows one to monitor one specific function memory usage. It is extremely simple to use.

```
import copy
import memory_profiler

@profile
def function():
    x = list(range(1000000))  # allocate a big list
    y = copy.deepcopy(x)
    del x
    return y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    function()
```

To invoke it:

```
python -m memory_profiler memory-profile-me.py
```

This will print output similar to below:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4                             @profile
     5      9.11 MB      0.00 MB   def function():
     6     40.05 MB     30.94 MB       x = list(range(1000000)) # allocate a big list
     7     89.73 MB     49.68 MB       y = copy.deepcopy(x)
     8     82.10 MB     -7.63 MB       del x
     9     82.10 MB      0.00 MB       return y
```

Even, detail explanation of the same is given at: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html