# Working Around Memory Error While Importing Data in Python

Tags: python, memory

I am attempting to import data -- in the form of many, large .dat files -- into python for computational simulations. The files themselves are simply strings of data, and I want to put them into two (eventually one) arrays of positional data, separated by file. Python will import one just fine, but when it gets to around 1/3 of the way through the second set (each set is 159 files) it crashes and cites MemoryError. I clearly understand the meaning of the error, but I have tried every solution on this site, and nothing works. Does anyone have any suggestions to circumvent this issue? Unfortunately, I will ultimately need all of the data together as one piece, so any sort of chunking (unless it only applies to the importing itself) will not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

### Edit 1

In response to helpful sarcasm, I am currently attempting to create the arrays using

```
xfile_list = glob.glob('Path\\/*dat')

xpos = []

for file_path in xfile_list:
    xpos.append(genfromtxt(file_path, delimiter = '\t'))
```

to import the files from a given directory (and duplicated to encompass ypos). Moreover, the data itself totals 108158*1470= 158992260 elements, at 1.6GB for each set. This ultimately implies that I am looking to work with two times this amount in a single array.

Comment: You can try to write it in such a way that you can force garbage collection to free up memory held by the first file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641717/manual-garbage-collection-in-python

Comment: Congratulations to trying all the solutions on this site. During this exhausting work you might have noticed, good questions provide a piece of code and clear facts allowing others to help you. You might start with showing a piece of code you use and summing amount of data you are trying to get into memory.